# If I allocate MDLAsset using metal, then inititialize an SCNNode using that asset, are the SCNGeometrySource objects copied to non-Metal buffers?

Tags: ios, scenekit, apple-model-io

If I allocate an `MDLAsset` and `SCNNode` like so

```
let device: MTLDevice = (sceneView?.device)!
let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "obj")
let asset = MDLAsset(url: url! as URL, vertexDescriptor: nil, bufferAllocator: allocator)

guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else {
      print("Failed to get mesh from obj asset")
      return nil
}

let node = SCNNode.init(mdlObject: object)
let geometrySources = node.geometry.sources
```

Are my `geometrySource` objects backed by Metal buffers, or has the process gone and copied the data in NSData?

Answer (score 1):

After experimentation, it is indeed the case that unless you explicitly initialize a `SCNGeometrySource` with a metal buffer it will be backed by a non-mutable `NSData` buffer. This is even if the `obj` file was loaded into an `MDLAsset` using an `MTLMeshBufferAllocator` in the initial setup.